# css hover not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a textbox. When i hover upon it, using chrome, it works fine. However, none of the IE versions are seems to recognize the hozer effect. Here is my css file.

```
.myOnlyTextbox
{
    background-color:White;
}

.myOnlyTextbox:focus
{
    background-color: #FFDFBF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.myOnlyTextbox:disabled
{
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.myOnlyTextbox:hover:enabled
{
    background-color: #FFB66C;
}
```

and here is my master file

```
<!DOCTYPE xhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server" >

    <title></title>
   <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

and in the child pages, I am using this header:

```
asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="../Styles/myTextbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </asp:Content>
```

and in the body tag, i define textbox like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchByBowzerNo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ByNo" 
                    CssClass="myOnlyTextbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I use this css in almost all browsers? any idea?

Comment: post your rendered html code

Comment: Its a huge file. however, here is what is generated on the textbox           <td class="style3">
  <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchByBowzerNo" type="text" id="MainContent_txtSearchByBowzerNo" class="myOnlyTextbox" />
            </td>

Comment: The `:enabled` and `:disabled` pseudo classes are not supported in IE lower 9. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t33

Comment: so what am i supposed to do now? I want a nice hover effect in IE.

Comment: add an other class when enabled. and move hovering to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:enabled and :disabled aren't supported in IE < 9; so a fall-back might be required... Try to use selectivizr.js....  CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.  http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: go to this http://selectivizr.com/ website and download the js file and add in to your header file...

Comment: ok... lets see if i can get it going ... one more thing.. shall i add it in the master file or the child page?

Comment: add it in your master page only.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/selectivizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
        <![endif]-->

Comment: @Gopikrishna you forgot to mention that you need another library to use it, like jquery

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/selectivizr.js"></script>

Comment: yes yes i have added it prior to adding that script... heres how i added the jquery file in master page head block. <head runat="server" >
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/selectivizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
        <![endif]-->

Comment: If Selectivizr does not work check the doctype at the top of your HTML. You must use a proper doctype; the most up-to-date for HTML5 is “<!DOCTYPE html>”.

If Selectivizr does not work check the doctype at the top of your HTML. You must use a proper doctype; the most up-to-date for HTML5 is “<!DOCTYPE html>”.

If Selectivizr does not work check the doctype at the top of your HTML. You must use a proper doctype; the most up-to-date for HTML5 is “<!DOCTYPE html>”.  refer to this site... http://www.ehow.com/how_12086308_use-css3-selectors-ie6-ie7.html

Comment: Here is what the Doctype is shown on the top of the master page. <!DOCTYPE xhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: nope, still Not working... I wrote this on top of my master file (Before anything) <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: please go through this website http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp and add accordingly...

Comment: I am sorry but its still not working, i have done exactly as you told me

Answer (score 0):

maybe try without multiple pseudo-elements :

```
.myOnlyTextbox:hover
{
    background-color: #FFB66C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rules to the following

```
[disabled].myOnlyTextbox, [readonly].myOnlyTextbox
{
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.myOnlyTextbox:hover
{
    background-color: #FFB66C;
}
```